# SpagoBI Dataset & Database connection time is very high

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, spagobi

I am using SpagoBI 5.1 and database is Oracle 11g. Both the server i.e SpagoBI & Oracle are on the same LAN.

LAN Bandwidth is 1GBPS to 10GBPS.

Both of my server configuration is high.

With 64GB RAM & 2-i7 processors.

When I run my query on sqlplus on Oracle server, it takes 10 seconds to execute.

But when I run the same query using dataset of SpagoBI, it takes 2 minutes.

So how to decrease this communication time of SpagoBI with Database?

Comment: try to update your query use joins in place of subqueries. use less columns. It will improved the performance of the connection

Answer (score 0):

How many rows of data and columns are involved ? Which SpagoBI report engine are you using?

It might be a difference in seeing data almost immediately in sqlplus versus only after all rows have been returned and processed through spagobi's reporting engine .

Try requesting only required columns and a smaller number of rows as an initial test.